# Count of rows in current data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to return a row count of the current data set shown below but can't seem to get it done. If anyone has suggestions they would be a huge help!

```
select id, driver_id, mc_unit_no, message_send_date, message_text,out_zone_id
from mc_message

where CHARINDEX('No', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('Load', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('Preassigned', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('at', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('this', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('time', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('sent', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('by', message_text)>0
  and CHARINDEX('loadmaster', message_text)>0
    and message_send_date > DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())

 ORDER BY out_zone_id,message_send_date
```

Comment: Have you tried a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: [Here is a start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You say you haven't been able to get it to work. What about your attempt(s) didn't work? What were your attempts?

Comment: have tried to add                                                                                                                         
  ` COUNT(*)`                                                                                                                            
       to the end of the statement. honestly I am not super advanced in SQL but learning. I really need to understand where to insert the count(*) into the statement to return the row count on the bottom of the page for a generated report.

Comment: Do you need count as a separate column along with existing column or just count of rows? @user13273056

Comment: @RaviDesai  Just a count of rows